# Moderators can star their own messages on Chat, while regular users can't

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, moderators, chat, moderator-abilities

Bill the Lizard, a moderator on Chat, [said](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/chats/message/8998?offset=-420) that he can star his own messages. I don't think anyone should be allowed to star their own messages on Chat, even moderators. I don't see how it could be useful, so I think that this is a bug and **should be removed**.

Comment: In my own defense, someone asked me to try it.  I'm not just that vain.  ;)

Comment: I see you're very addicted to the new chat feature. You should totally drop that and try jQuery.

Comment: don't overdo it! ;-)

Comment: If you're an owner you can star your own messages. Not that I know exactly how?!?!?!

Comment: @Xaade: you can pin 'em, but you can't star 'em.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yea; it does seem like it should be.

I vote for the following image to pop up when someone tries to flag their own message:

[image]
<sub>(source: [motifake.com](http://www.motifake.com/image/demotivational-poster/0807/whos-awesome-awesome-demotivational-poster-1216390759.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 3):

While we're at it can we stop dangling the carrot? If the link isn't there we won't be tempted to click on it, only to receive this severe telling off:

[image]

Comment: this is `status-completed` now :-)

Comment: what link did that???? The edit, or flag. Certainly not Andy's head?

Answer (score 1):

Room owners can also star their messages, but the process of going about this actually appears as a legitimate bug and not an allowed power.

Comment: It's the same for mods, they can't actually star their own messages, but they can pin/unpin them to end up with a star

Comment: Oh noes.... they found my trick. Don't take it away!!!!

Comment: I used to get a sense of accomplishment when my messages were starred. Now that I have the cheat-code, the game isn't fun to play anymore.